# Can I add template partials in a loop in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to populate my application.yaml based on my deploy environment. each deploy environment can have 1 or more clients configured and configuring each client is multiple lines in my yaml. Is it possible to create a partial template like

```
> <%= @environmentName %>:
>      serviceId: <%= @environmentName %>
```

and deploy it a dynamic number of times in my application yaml template. Also is there a better fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use normal partials API (`render`). However since it's YAML, it might be easier to construct the data structure in actual Ruby code instead of a template and then just write it out by calling `.to_yaml`.

Comment: Do you have examples of code snippets doing this- I am pretty new to chef